# facebook login view does not have any option to close it

Tags: ios4, facebook-graph-api

I'm facing a strange problem here, i have used a sample code of graph api's (reallylongaddress-iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API-59e6399,  Created by , https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) which was available on github. And i faced these problems:-

1)  I'm having a share button of my own , when i click on it to login to fb a white view (or popup ) apears for almost 5 seconds and it appears evry time when i click on share button to share something on my facebook wall, even if i'm logged in . I reduced this problem to only one time.

2)  The second and main problem now i'm facing is that on login it doesn't have any close button on it , and user must have to login ,other wise the application will not continue. **Can i place a close button on this fb login web view?**

NOTE:I have also used the fbconnect earlier but i dont wanna use publish dialog box ,, which shows user a dialog box and then user can press on "pulish" or "skip" button. **instead i want that what ever the user wants to share on wall can be shared on just one tap on a button.** That is why i have used this sample code, but it also has these two problems i have specified above.

Please help me with these 2 problems above or suggest me any other alternative option which does not have the "publish.stream" dialog box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem and placed a close button on the login view. and on tab of this button i closed the login web view

Answer (score 1):

In this condition Facebook controller are called by `UINavigationController`.